# CardView inside TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

i have 2 cardviews inside a table layout.
CODE:

```
                <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:stretchColumns="*"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/card_view3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_margin="5dp" android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="180dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:background="#ffdbff3d">


       </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
          android:layout_margin="5dp" android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_height="180dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:background="#ffdbff3d">


       </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

     </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
```

there is a picture inside cv1 and the problem is that when i set picture(in cv1) width to    fill_parent    the picture takes all the row and wont fill just the cv1 and even when i dont set fill parent its doing its job!

and i even cant set a background for my cv and i dont know why.

i hope u can solve it.

Comment: Don't use table Layout- just an advice

Comment: well what can i use instead? @ViktorYakunin

Comment: Please, if you are going to ask a question, at least format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use TableLayout, it has poor performance. Solution:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffdbff3d" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffdbff3d" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Worse to mention - if you use weight than you should specify what attribute it would affect, in this particular case `layout_width` so you should set it to `"0dp"`.

Comment: I don't think you need to specify which attribute it will affect, it is decided by the orientation of the Linearlayout.